# how can I change the color of my outline?

Tags: beamer

My outline is written in gold color, How can I change it in black ?

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\setbeamerfont{structure}{family=\rmfamily} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usetheme{default} 
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\newcommand{\SMIT}{\mathfrak{P}}
\newcommand{\vc}[3]{\overset{#2}{\underset{#3}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\prob}[1]{\mathbb{P}\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\cprob}[2]{\mathbb{P}\left[#1 \;\middle\vert\; #2\right]}
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\mathbb{E}\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\Et}[1]{\mathbb{E}_{t}\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\Econd}[2]{\mathbb{E}_{#1}\left[#2\right]}
\newcommand{\VAR}[1]{\mathbb{V}\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor#1\right\rfloor}
\newcommand{\norma}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}
\newcommand{\tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\quadre}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\graffe}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\Sm}[1]{\mathcal{S}\tonde{#1}}
\newcommand{\due}[2]{\left(\begin{array}{c}#1\\#2\end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\duedue}[4]{\left(\begin{array}{ll}#1 & #2\\#3 & #4\end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\tre}[3]{\left(\begin{array}{c}#1\\#2\\#3\end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\quattro}[4]{\left(\begin{array}{c}#1\\#2\\#3\\#4\end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\I}[1]{\mathds{1}_{\left\{#1\right\}}}
\newcommand{\lra}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Ra}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\bart}{\overline{t}}
\newcommand{\Rset}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\spei}{\mathrm{E}_{i-1}}
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\bi}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\ei}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\ben}{\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\een}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\blem}{\begin{lem}}
\newcommand{\elem}{\end{lem}}
\newcommand{\bteo}{\begin{theorem}}
\newcommand{\eteo}{\end{theorem}}
\newcommand{\bcor}{\begin{corollary}}
\newcommand{\ecor}{\end{corollary}}
\newcommand{\brem}{\begin{rmk1}}
\newcommand{\erem}{\end{rmk1}}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\cond}{\;\middle\vert\;}
\newcommand{\accapo}{\nonumber\\}
\newcommand{\convp}{\overset{p}{\longrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\convlone}{\stackrel{L^1}{\longrightarrow}}
\newcommand*{\second}{^{\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
\newcommand*{\third}{^{\prime\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
\newcommand*{\fourth}{^{\prime\prime\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
\newcommand{\idlen}{\SIT_{n}}
\newcommand{\kidlen}{\SIT_{n,k}}
\newcommand{\bidlen}{\SIT_{n,1}}
\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}
\newcommand{\plim}{\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\dlim}{\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\df}{\stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=}}
\newcommand\myeq{\mathrel{\stackrel{\makebox[0pt]{\mbox{\normalfont\tiny def}}}{=}}}
\newcommand{\dav}[1]{\color{red}\fbox{DAV}: #1\color{black} }
\newcommand{\Var}[1]{\mathbf{Var}\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\Cov}[1]{\mathbf{Cov}\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\EQ}[1]{\mathbf{E}^{\mathcal Q}\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\EP}[1]{\mathbf{E}^{\mathcal Q}\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\EC}[2]{\mathbf{E}\left[#1\left| #2 \right. \right]}
\newcommand{\SIT}{\mathfrak{S}}
\newcommand{\Ei}[2]{\mathbb{E}_{#1}\left[#2\right]}
\newcommand{\Op}[1]{O_p\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{o_p\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\matrice}[4]{\left( \begin{array}{cc} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4\end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\vettoredue}[2]{\left( \begin{array}{c} #1 \\ #2 \end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\de}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\dede}[2]{\frac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2^2}}
\newcommand{\stable}{\overset{L-st.}{\longrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\dsum}{\displaystyle\sum}
\newcommand{\dint}{\displaystyle\int}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newcommand{\ucp}{\vc{\longrightarrow}{\text{ucp}}{n\rightarrow\infty}}



\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
        draw,
        fill=red,
        single arrow,
        minimum height=2.5ex,
        line width=1pt,
        single arrow head extend=0.1ex
    }
}
\newcommand{\arrowdown}{%
\tikz [baseline=-1ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=-90,  yscale=.5, single arrow head extend=1mm] {};}
}
\newcommand{\arrowright}{%
\tikz [baseline=-0.5ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=0,  yscale=.4, single arrow head extend=1mm] {};}
}



\title[The Kelly Criterion on Asset Allocation] %(optional, use only with long paper titles)
{Application of the Kelly Criterion on Asset Allocation}

\date[December 17, 2018]{December 17, 2018}
\author[Tommaso Dell'Olmo]{Tommaso Dell'Olmo \\ \small{ Thesis Advisor}: \\ Giulia Livieri \\ Stefano Marmi}
\institute[University of Florence]{University of Florence \\ MSc in Finance and Risk Management}




\mode<presentation>


\useinnertheme{rounded}



\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty  %removes navigation bar

\definecolor{pacificorange}{cmyk}{.15,.45,1,0} %approved Pacific colors 2010
\definecolor{pacificgray}{cmyk}{0,.15,.35,.60}
\definecolor{pacificlgray}{cmyk}{0,0,.2,.4}
\definecolor{pacificcream}{cmyk}{.05,.05,.15,0}
\definecolor{deepyellow}{cmyk}{0,.17,.80,0}
\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{.49,.01,0,0}
\definecolor{lightbrown}{cmyk}{.09,.15,.34,0}
\definecolor{deepviolet}{cmyk}{.79,1,0,.15}
\definecolor{deeporange}{cmyk}{0,.59,1,18}
\definecolor{dustyred}{cmyk}{0,.7,.45,.4}
\definecolor{grassgreen}{RGB}{92,135,39}
\definecolor{pacificblue}{RGB}{59,110,143}
\definecolor{pacificgreen}{cmyk}{.15,0,.45,.30}
\definecolor{deepblue}{cmyk}{1,.57,0,2}
\definecolor{turquoise}{cmyk}{.43,0,.24,0}



\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme[named=pacificorange]{structure}



%\setbeamercovered{invisible}
%\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default]
%\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=}

%\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=}
%\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=gray}
%\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{../TesiLeoncini/Latex/immaginitesi/logo.jpg}\vspace{220pt}} 

%\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=white}



\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
    \makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

%\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
%\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.85\textwidth,-1cm)
%\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{../TesiLeoncini/Latex/immaginitesi/logo4.jpg} 
%\end{textblock*}}

\begin{frame}[c]{Outline}
\tableofcontents[]
\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\section{Introduction}


 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Outline}
 \tableofcontents[currentsection]
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you loading `graphicx` three times? In fact you don't need all the `\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{default} ` with beamer anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding this definition in your preamble should do the trick:

```
%% changing the fontcolor
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=black}
```

This will give you:

[image]

> Next time try to give a ***Minimal*** *working example*. Its easier that way.